# Yii2 - app assets

Tags: php, assets, yii2

Yii is great but assets is the thing that was always strange for me (since the 1.1 version).
I'm using Yii2 currently with Advanced app template. I want to register some css/js files in frontend `main` layout view (trying to use [HTML5UP Prologue Template](http://html5up.net/prologue)).
How it can be done? I placed my `css` files under `frontend/web/css` directory, `js` under `frontend/web/js` and layout images under `frontend/web/images` dir.

Under `frontend/assets` directory I created `PrologueAssets` class like this:

```
namespace frontend\assets;
use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class PrologueAssets extends AssetBundle {

    public $sourcePath = "@webroot";
    public $css = [
        'css/skel.css',
        'css/style.css',
        'css/style-wide.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/jquery.min.js',
        'js/jquery.scrolly.min.js',
        'js/jquery.scrollzer.min.js',
        'js/skel.min.js',
        'js/skel-layers.min.js',
        'js/init.js',
    ];

    static function register($view) {
        die(self::sourcePath);
        parent::register($view);
    }

}
```

Unfortunately none of these files are registered. How to do that?

Little second question - how to register css files only if eg IE8 or IE9 is detected?

Comment: What happens when you include the CSS and JS files on `AppAsset.php` (instead of `PrologueAssets.php`?

Comment: @PrabowoMurti - that was interesting. It tried to include the files but not in relation to base url but the current so it was working only on homepage. Pretty weird, ecpesially when at the same time the default yiis `site.css` is loaded properly.

Comment: I made a workaround - included the files in view using `Url::base()` to generate base url and by adding `css/...` or `js/...` to the end. I always thought assets are to complicated in Yii.

Answer (score 5):

You should simply try:

```
class PrologueAssets extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        ...
    ];
    public $js = [
        ...
    ];
}
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html

PS : assets management is currently being refactored :
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/pull/4855

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add two files,one under `frontend/web/css/custom.css` and `frontend/web/js/custom.js` I just found the frontend/assets/AppAsset.php and added them directly and the two files are loaded for every page i load.

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
        'css/custom.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/custom.js',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you register js or css for ie 8 only

```
namespace app\assets;
use yii\web\AssetBundle;
class IE8Assets extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css=[
            'css/ie8.css'
    ];
    public $cssOptions = ['condition' => 'lte IE9'];
    public $js =[
            'js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js',
            'js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js',
    ]; 
    public $jsOptions = ['condition' => 'lte IE9'];
}
```